# Functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, function, codeigniter

I have a model class that looks likes the following

```
function block_user()
{

  function is_in_blocked_list()
   {
     //line number 137...

   }
  function power_block()
  {
    is_in_blocked_list()  // doing some operations


  }

 if (condition)
 {
 power_block();
 }

}
```

But i am getting an error on is_in_blocked_list()

that is

```
Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\pname\application\models\admin\admin_user.php on line 137
```

Line 137 says that

```
$qry = "SELECT a FROM tblC WHERE username=?";
            $qry = $this->db->query($qry,array($userName));
```

i am new to php and codeigniter,how can i fix this problem ?

INFO :THANKS FOR THE DOWNVOTE [BUT YOUR ANSWER IS WORST :)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions need to ask on what they operate:

```
function block_user(Controller $controller)
{
    function is_in_blocked_list(Controller $controller)
    {
        //line number 137...
        $controller->.... (not $this->...)
    }
    function power_block(Controller $controller)
    {
        is_in_blocked_list($controller)  // doing some operations
    }
    if (condition)
    {
        power_block($controller);
    }
}
```

Replace the `Controller` type with the type of controller they should operate on, the general one in CI is called `CI_Controller` IIRC.

I would not consider this a good solution, but it probably shows the picture what you're conceptually doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `is_in_blocked_list()` and `power_block()` functions have their own variable scope and they don't belong to class. Move these functions directly to class, and use `$this->power_block()`. Like so:

```
function is_in_blocked_list()
{
 //line number 137...

}

function power_block()
{
    $this->is_in_blocked_list();  // doing some operations


}

function block_user()
{

 if (condition)
 {
    $this->power_block();
 }

}
```

Comment: Well,I know that : But is there anyway that i can do this inside the block_user function ? i just tried Functions inside functions in php.

Comment: I guess not. Maybe you can use anonymus functions as `use` keyword, but not sure. Why you don't what to make these functions part of class? You don't want them to be accessible? The add `private` keyword and function is only accessible inside that class(or extends). Like so: `private function block_user() { /*YOUR CODE*/ }`

Comment: Nothing about `private` its something about code visibility,actually there is no need of 2 functions there but i need it there,also if i can hold these two functions inside the main function it will be very nice to read.